# Tag icons (like on the original StackOverflow)

Tags: discussion, tags

Was wondering where we can submit tag icons like on Stackoverflow...

Could be cool to have an icon like this

[image: Pokemon Icon]

for the pokemon tag and all pokemon games.

[image: Tag Icons]

Comment: By the way - there's nothing stopping you from making a small userscript that added those images to the tags.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Stack Overflow, tag images are actually advertisement placement options - if you check the HTML, you'll see their CSS class is named `sponsor-tag-img`. If you click on one such tag, you'll see a number of sponsored links for the tag as well.

[image]

So... no, right now tag images can't be submitted.

Comment: Oh, so I guess that's why not every tag has one.

I'm kinda new to the stack exchange websites, so thanks for the info.

Comment: So that means we should make gaming.se so popular that game companies will pay to advertise here?

Comment: @Arkive Why not? After all, Stack Exchange Inc. has seen nothing but expenses from Gaming so far... except for the hits that went from here to SO, I guess. :)

Comment: **I AM GREATLY IN FAVOR OF THIS**. That is all.

Comment: I realise this was asked/answered almost two years ago, but the SE model has changed a bit in that time, and we as a community have grown substantially. (I'm guessing) we haven't been approached to be 'sponsored' as such, could we do the reverse, i.e. approach game companies instead? I daresay companies like Mojang would spring at the chance to let us use their 'grass cube' minecraft icon. That way, the games get some advertising, and we get our pretty tags.

Comment: @Robotnik Nothing has changed in the last few years regarding ads, however, so I'm afraid this answer is still valid. Mojang could happily gives us a green flag to do so, but they'd hardly _pay_ for the privilege.